# How to load all nodes in kendo treelist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-treelist

I have a treeList which use remote binding, meaning the nodes use lazy loading. Rarely, It happens that I need to process all nodes (client side).

Is there a way to load all nodes at once ?

Example of lazy loading : [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/IhamE)

Comment: please check http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding. For this you have to return all data in given format in first call.